# Why does ways to pick $12$ elements from $5$ different types not equal to $5^{12}$?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is how many ways you can pick $12$ donuts from $5$ different varieties. I thought I can just pick $1$ donut at a time. Each time I have $5$ choices for $1$ donut so it would be $5^{12}$ ways but it’s wrong.

Comment: I assume it is because order doesn't matter.  Picking  Raspberry, Raspberry, Old Fashioned, Glazed, Buttermilk is the same thin as picking Buttermilk, Raspberry, Old Fashioned, Raspberry, Glazed.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  This should be tagged [tag:combinatorics] not [tag:ordinary-differential-equations]

Comment: It's kind of frustrating as in combinatorics classes they tend to intuitively expect phrases like "number of ways" to be clear in context.  The ways to choose donuts *implies* that you put the donuts in the bag and order doesn't matter.  But the number of ways to select speakers for a conference, order might matter.  Ways to put rings on your fingers ... does it matter which rings go above or under each other?  Anyway... if you want to line the donuts on a tray one after another.  The answer *is* $5^{12}$.  But if you are dumping them in a bag, it isn't.

Comment: @fleablood Indeed, in a literal interpretation "ways to pick donuts" might lead to even more posibilities (picking them with your left vs right hand, for example) :(

Comment: Or may likely "I want that cherry glazed with the nice bubbly bit on the side but not that other cherry glazed with the crust brown bit on top".  It's a mixed blessing. On the one hand perhaps more than any other math branch combinatorics is *practical* real world so it should be intuitive. But there should be a point where we say "now that you understand the difference lets formally and consistantly define the many ways we can 'pick things'".

Comment: .... actually when I hear "ways to pick donuts" I tend to think "okay.... I could pick them based on personal taste, or I could pick them based on price, or on availability, or randomly, or ...."  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I thought I can just pick 1 donut at a time."

You can.  But that differentiates the order in which you pick them.  Picking a cherry glazed first and a buttermilk bar second will be different than picking a buttermilk bar first and a cherry glazed third.

So the number of ways to display twelve donuts in a row from $12$ different types *is* indeed $5^{12}$.

However it is assumed (perhaps frustrating in that they do not specifically state so) that order doesn't matter-- that you are just going to put the in a bag and you will eat them in any order you like--  That the customer is going to say "Gimme 4 glazed old fashioneds, 3 cherry glazed, and 5 buttermilk bars" and is not going to say "Oh and make sure you  put two of the glazed old fashioned between the second and third buttermilk bars and that none of the cherry glazeds are next to each other".

Answer (score 3):

That would be correct if you were to compute the number of different line-ups of the donuts. However it is not the number of different bags of donuts, that is, disregarding the order in which they come.